# PowerPoint Add-In on Android Mobile device

Tags: c#, android, c#-4.0, powerpoint-2010

My purpose is creating a Powerpoint Presentation with extended features (the add-in function), and allow displaying on all kind of devices (desktop, mobile, tablet, TV screen).

I created a PowerPoint add-in by C#, in which the PowerPoint is provided more extended features on my custom menu. For the desktop, there is no problem with displaying, the menu is displayed. But on android device, or other kind of device (iOS, etc) this menu does not appear. I think the issue comes from the powerpoint reader software on android device. They make the software as simply as possible. So the menu is not shown.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like you'll have to write a full-up version of PowerPoint for the devices you want to support.  As you may imagine, there's a reason why these aren't common.

Comment: it's quite hard, and takes a lot of efforts. Is there any other alternatives?

Comment: None that I'm aware of